# Running concurrent code on the current thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I am trying to run concurrent C# code on a single thread.

My goal is to call two or more functions simultaneously. Those functions consist in a long treatment which is not CPU-bound, i.e., fetching data from a database. I would like to start executing those functions at the same moment so that they all reach the point when they call (synchronously) a deeper part of the backend and "wait" for the backend's result (which can take up to several seconds). Those functions are not dependant on one another.

My work environment is very restricted and I cannot write code which could lead to spawning additional threads, and I am provided with synchronous functions which execute a database fetch by waiting until it's finished.

I've tried searching for a similar problem and could only find [one post which relates](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-concurrency/single-threaded-concurrency.html). Most searches revolved around Tasks, custom thread pools and custom job scheduler.

Does anybody have a solution to my initial problem, and/or can anybody confirm whether it's even possible in C# to dispatch slices of execution time between several functions on the same thread the way an operating system round-robin scheduler would?

To illustrate with tasks, the expected behaviour would be to start all three tasks at the same time to reach the `Thead.Sleep(1000)` instruction as soon as possible, the difference being that the sleeping timer would tick whether the enclosing task is active or not.

```cs
    public static void Main()
    {
        var task1 = new Task(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task {0} (syncTask) executing on Thread {1}", Task.CurrentId, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // this would be the backend call, which would resolve in about one second whether this code actively waits for it or not
            Console.WriteLine("Task {0} (syncTask) executing on Thread {1}", Task.CurrentId, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        });
        var task2 = new Task(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task {0} (syncTask) executing on Thread {1}", Task.CurrentId, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // this would be the backend call, which would resolve in about one second whether this code actively waits for it or not
            Console.WriteLine("Task {0} (syncTask) executing on Thread {1}", Task.CurrentId, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        });
        var task3 = new Task(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task {0} (syncTask) executing on Thread {1}", Task.CurrentId, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // this would be the backend call, which would resolve in about one second whether this code actively waits for it or not
            Console.WriteLine("Task {0} (syncTask) executing on Thread {1}", Task.CurrentId, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        });
        // note: comment out either method 1 or method 2
        // method 1: is single threaded but synchronous
        task1.RunSynchronously();
        task2.RunSynchronously();
        task3.RunSynchronously();
        // method 2: is async but multithreaded
        task1.Start();
        task2.Start();
        task3.Start();
    }
```

Comment: _"and/or can anybody confirm whether it's even possible in C# to dispatch slices of execution time between several functions on the same thread the way an operating system round-robin scheduler would?"_ - kind of sounds like how I/O Completion port handlers work but it also sounds like you have like an overall orchestration that can be broken up.  Maybe _TPL Dataflow_ is to your liking.

Comment: Generally, you want to avoid `new Task` and instead use the `Task.Run` helper method.

Comment: Also, `RunSynchronously` causes the task to complete on the current thread, blocking it in the process.  The net effect is akin to old school `new Thread` only to `Join` it which also blocks the current thread _defeating the purpose of threads in the first place_.

Comment: What database do you access? What you want to do can only be done, if the database offers an API that already supports .net async or uses functions with callbacks

Comment: @NineBerry agreed, I'm pretty certain the middleware accesses a database server, so it should have its own logic for making an async request synchronous

Comment: @Deleted Unless I misunderstood what TPL Dataflow offers, let me rephrase. I call a middleware method, let's say `db.Exec();`, which is exposed as synchronous. What I wish to achieve, having no way of altering the content of this method, is to *start executing* `db1.Exec()`, then *pause its execution* and *start executing* `db2.Exec()`, then round-robin between both calls to wait for them to finish. Though the more I search about it, the more I feel like it is simply not possible.